# Odoo class differences

Tags: odoo

When creating class sometimes use osv.osv, also we use models.Model
What is the basic difference between these two?
Is there any advantages over another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before version 7,

`osv` is a class and an OpenERP descriptor class and all the class( model) must inherit it for OpenERP module deployment.

`osv` class inside in OSV module in OpenERP server , which content all the OpenERP properties like you can see _column, _defaults and other many things there such as nameetc so we must inherit in our openerp model (class)

In version 7,

The ORM, short for Object-Relational Mapping, is a central part of OpenERP.

In OpenERP, the data model is described and manipulated through Python classes and objects. It is the ORM job to bridge the gap -- as transparently as possible for the developer -- between Python and the underlying relational database (PostgreSQL), which will provide the persistence we need for our objects.

`osv.osv` and `orm.Model` is deprecated and it still works for backward compatibility. You should use `models.Model` instead.

In version 8+,

The model transition was

`osv.osv` ---> `orm.Model` ---> `models.Model`

`osv.TransientModel` ---> `orm.TransientModel` ---> `models.TransientModel`

Comment: Hello can you please provide the documentation link where all the changes are documented properly ? I mean for which OLD API convention we need to use which NEW API convention. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#porting-from-the-old-api-to-the-new-api

Answer (score 5):

The `osv.osv` was used in the former API. 
It is deprecated. it still works but should be avoided.

With the new API `models.Model` should be used.